# Why is my external WD MyPassport 2TB drive suddenly extremely slow?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, hdd

I have a WD MyPassport 2TB drive in an external USB 3.0 enclosure that I use for backup purposes.

Every few months, I manually copy my entire Documents and Music folders to the external drive.

There's about 1.2TB on it now.

Problem is, I plugged it in for the first time in a while and accessing data on it is EXTREMELY slow.  Like, to get a directly listing in Finder takes about a full minute.  To copy of directory with 1GB from it will take close to an hour.

The drive appears to be working, but it's running extremely slowly.

I may have done an Mac OS upgrade or update since the last time I used the drive ... I'm currently running macOS High Sierra version 10.13.6

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us your activity monitor CPU usage

Comment: since you manually copy files to it, it could be that the mac needs quite some time to find the files. Also while SSD do not need defrag, the HDD do.